# Which kind of Facebook App is necessary to implement Facebook Social with CocoonJS

Tags: facebook, cocoonjs

We've been creating a game for a while now and we'd like to integrate Facebook with CocoonJS, in order to publish game results or even some kind of message in-game. We would like to know which kind of app we'd have to create that allow us to integrate our game with Facebook Social. https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Thank you!